# How to print the list returned by a function call in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am using the following function to print a list

```
let rec print_list = function
  [] -> ()
| e::l -> print_int e ; print_string " " ; print_list l;;
```

I am using the following function to reverse a list

```
let rec rev l =
  match l with
    [] -> []
  | h::t -> rev t @ [h];;
```

I am using the following to print the reversed list:

```
print_list rev [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

However, in my terminal when I run my file named `reverse.ml` using

```
ocaml reverse.ml
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: This function has type int list -> unit
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

I am curious as to the syntax for printing the resulting list in OCaml. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is the following:

```
print_list (rev [1; 2; 3; 4])
```

Inner function needs to be wrapped in parenthesis.